# Check MassPay payment status without IPN/PDT

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, masspay

We operate an application that utilizes PayPal's Mass Payments API to handle bulk payments of our users' customers. We have a listener set up to handle the IPNs for these payments, and process the successes/failures accordingly.

Recently, we discovered that one of our major clients had mistakenly disabled IPNs from their PayPal account, causing a large number of Payments to not have their final status in our application. While the "Resend IPN" option was available, is there an API or anything we can call out to to check payment status for these without relying solely on IPNs?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) , but you need sufficient access to that particular account which means the account holder have to grant you the permission to view the transaction.